# Работа с SQL Server через Docker на MacOs

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, macos, mac

Установила SQL Server по туториалу из интернета, но совсем не понимаю как дальше работать с запросами через Docker, куда стоит перейти или что нажать для того, чтобы начать работу?

Comment: что значит "начать работу"? если вы запустили сервер значит он уже работает и вы можете его использовать для своих задач

Comment: если контейнер с сервером запущен и настроен маппинг портов, то берете SQL-клиент (SSMS, командную строку, или еще какое приложение) и коннектитесь по указанным реквизитам.

Comment: я просто не очень понимаю что требуется открыть для того, чтобы начать вводить запросы. командная строка слишком неудобна, мне sql server для лабораторных работ нужен... какое приложение следует установить для работы с ним на маке?

Comment: Если для запросов, то думаю подойдет [Azure Data Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Data Studio действительно подходит

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).